# How to print proprely in python using for loops

Tags: python, printing, dictionary

I was wondering if I'm just trying to do something the wrong way or if I'm close to a viable solution.

I have to print a chess board from a Dictionary given by the teacher.

This is my code so far :

```
def printBoard(board):
x = 0
for x in range(0,7):
    print("|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|")
    print("|             |             |             |             |             |             |             |             |")
    print("|",board[0,x],"|",board[1,x],"|",board[2,x],"|",board[3,x],"|",board[4,x],"|",board[5,x],"|",board[6,x],board[7,x])
    print("|             |             |             |             |             |             |             |             |")

print("|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|")

board =   {
                (0,0):"Rook[B]",(1,0):"Knight[B]",(2,0):"Bishop[B]", (3,0):"Queen[B]",   (4,0):"King[B]", (5,0):"Bishop[B]", (6,0):"Knight[B]",(7,0):"Rook[B]",
                (0,1):"Pawn[B]",(1,1):"Pawn[B]",    (2,1):"Pawn[B]",(3,1):"Pawn[B]",    (4,1):"Pawn[B]",(5,1):"Pawn[B]",(6,1):"Pawn[B]",    (7,1):"Pawn[B]",
                (0,2):"EMPTY",   (1,2):"EMPTY",       (2,2):"EMPTY",   (3,2):"EMPTY",       (4,2):"EMPTY",   (5,2):"EMPTY",   (6,2):"EMPTY",       (7,2):"EMPTY",
                (0,3):"EMPTY",   (1,3):"EMPTY",       (2,3):"EMPTY",   (3,3):"EMPTY",       (4,3):"EMPTY",   (5,3):"EMPTY",   (6,3):"EMPTY",       (7,3):"EMPTY",
                (0,4):"EMPTY",   (1,4):"EMPTY",       (2,4):"EMPTY",   (3,4):"EMPTY",       (4,4):"EMPTY",   (5,4):"EMPTY",   (6,4):"EMPTY",       (7,4):"EMPTY",
                (0,5):"EMPTY",   (1,5):"EMPTY",       (2,5):"EMPTY",   (3,5):"EMPTY",       (4,5):"EMPTY",   (5,5):"EMPTY",   (6,5):"EMPTY",       (7,5):"EMPTY",
                (0,6):"Pawn[N]",(1,6):"Pawn[N]",    (2,6):"Pawn[N]",(3,6):"Pawn[N]",    (4,6):"Pawn[N]",(5,6):"Pawn[N]",(6,6):"Pawn[N]",    (7,6):"Pawn[N]",
                (0,7):"Rook[N]",(1,7):"Knight[N]",(2,7):"Bishop[N]", (3,7):"Queen[N]",   (4,7):"King[N]", (5,7):"Bishop[N]", (6,7):"Knight[N]",(7,7):"Rook[N]",
                }

printBoard(board)
```

My problem is that I cannot align my column.

Maybe I should just send the dictionary into 8 different list and print them that way ?

Thanks!

Edit  :

Output : [image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the methods `ljust` and `rjust` on `str` and `unicode` objects to make sure a string always prints in constant length with a padding character of your choosing. In your case:

```
board[0, x].ljust(11)
```

which evaluates to e.g.

```
'Pawn[B]      '
```

So a row would be printed like

```
print("|", board[0, x].ljust(11), "|", board[1, x].ljust(11, ' '), ...)
```

but a more compact version would be:

```
for x in range(8):
    row = [board[y, x] for y in range(8)]
    print('|%s|' % '|'.join(cell.lpad(13) for cell in row)
```

**NOTE1:** the `range` needs to be `range(0, 8)` not `range(0, 7)` because it's a non-inclusive range; also, `range(0, N)` is equivalent to just `range(N)`.

**NOTE2:** if you need to pad using a string other than `' '`, you can pass an optional second parameter to `ljust` (and `rjust`).

Comment: thanks for the tip I added the .ljust and a sep='' at the end and it works

Comment: @SKTLZ: why the `sep=''` though?